# Multi-page form attempt

Tags: php, mvc, laravel

I have just started playing around with L4 and would like to get some feedback on how I implemented a multi-page form

Here are my routes:

```
Route::model('appointment', 'Appointment');
Route::get('appointment/book_new/{appointment}', array('as' => 'booking-form', 'uses' => 'AppointmentBookingController@index') );
Route::post('appointment/book_new/verify/{appointment}', 'AppointmentBookingController@verify');
Route::post('appointment/book_new/success/{appointment}', 'AppointmentBookingController@success');
```

Here is my controller:

```
class AppointmentBookingController extends BaseController {

    public function index(Appointment $appt)
    {                   
        return View::make('appointment/bookings/book',  array('appt' => $appt));
    }

    public function verify(Appointment $appt){
        $fields = array('name', 'email', 'description');

        // Declare the rules for the form validation
        $rules = array(
            'name'        => 'required',
            'email'       => 'required|email',
            'description' => 'required',
        );

        // Create a new validator instance from our validation rules
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // If validation fails, we'll exit the operation now.
        if ($validator->fails())
        {           
            foreach($fields as $v)
            {
                Session::flash($v, Input::get($v));
            }           
            return View::make('appointment/bookings/book',  array('appt' => $appt, 'errors' => $validator->messages()));
        } else {
            Session::put('booking-form-index', Input::all());
            return View::make('/appointment/bookings/verify',  array('appt' => $appt));
        }
    }

    public function success(Appointment $appt){
        // validate, if valid save the booking.
            // don't do anything for now
            var_dump ( Session::get('booking-form-index') );
            exit();

            // display the success page
            // return View::make('/appointment/bookings/success',  array('appt' => $appt)); 
}
```

Here are my views ( book.blade.php )

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/appointment/book_new/verify/'. $appt->id )) }}

<!-- CSRF Token -->
{{ Form::token() }}

<!-- Name -->
<div>
    {{ Form::text('name', Session::get('name'), array('placeholder' => 'Name')) }}  
    {{ $errors->first('name') }}
</div>

<!-- Email -->
<div >
    {{ Form::text('email', Session::get('email'), array('placeholder' => 'email@email.com')) }}  
    {{ $errors->first('email') }}
</div>
<!-- Description -->
<div >
    {{  Form::textarea ('description') }}
    {{ $errors->first('description') }}
</div>

<!-- Form actions -->
{{ Form::submit('Click Me!') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

verify.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'appointment/book_new/success/' . $appt->id )) }}

{{  Form::text('validate') }}

{{ Form::submit('Click Me!') }}   

{{ Form::close() }}
```

success.blade.php

```
Success
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty standard to me! The only minor tweak I would make just for readability is to eliminate the `else` in `AppointmentBookingController::verify()`; since you `return` in the `if`, the `else` block is not necessary, and using guard clauses like this will (arguably) make your code more readable. See [Invert "if" statement to reduce nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268132/invert-if-statement-to-reduce-nesting?rq=1).